# If $x,y,z\in\mathbb R^+$ are in Harmonic Progression, prove that $z\cdot e^{x-y}+x\cdot e^{z-y}\ge\frac{2xz}y$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, harmonic-numbers

> If $x,y,z\in\mathbb R^+$ are in Harmonic Progression, prove that $z\cdot e^{x-y}+x\cdot e^{z-y}\ge\frac{2xz}y$

Given, $\frac1y-\frac1x=\frac1z-\frac1y\implies z(x-y)=x(y-z)$

I tried AM-GM inequality on $ze^{x-y}, xe^{z-y}$ but couldn't conclude.

I tried weighted AM-GM inequality on $e^{x-y}$ with weight $z$ and $e^{z-y}$ with weight $x$ but couldn't conclude.

I tried AM-HM inequality but couldn't conclude.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inequality is equivalent to:
$$\dfrac{e^x}{x} + \dfrac{e^z}{z}\geq2\dfrac{e^y}{y}\iff \dfrac{e^x}{x} + \dfrac{e^z}{z}\geq\left(\frac 1x + \frac 1z\right)e^{\tfrac{2xz}{x+z}}.$$
After some more rearrangement, this is equivalent to:
$$\frac{z}{x+z}e^x + \frac{x}{x+z}e^z\geq e^{\tfrac{x\cdot z}{x+z} + \tfrac{z\cdot x}{x+z}},$$
which is just weighted AM-GM.

Interestingly, the Jensen's inequality is not strong enough in the first form as $\dfrac{e^x}{x}$ is convex but not increasing.

Comment: Jensen's inequality does not require that the function is increasing.

Comment: no, but after applying it you do not immediately get $y$, but an upper bound of it in this problem.

Comment: I see. Your answer (+1) gave me the idea for a solution using Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

As @dezdichado said, the inequality can be rewritten as
$$
 \frac 1y e^y \le \frac 12 \left( \frac 1x e^x + \frac 1z e^z\right) \, .
$$
With the substitution $x=1/u$, $y=1/v$, $z=1/w$ this becomes
$$
  v e^{1/v} \le \frac 12 \left( u e^{1/u} + w e^{1/w}\right) 
$$
with $v = (u+w)/2$, this is Jensen's inequality for the convex function $f(x) = x e^{1/x}$.